# Building and installing the app on the device react-native window and android

Tags: react-native

I just started with **react-native**.
But I have a problem with the replay of the project. I use the command **[react-native run-android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTIOC.png)**, this annoys me an error see capture.

Comment: Your post says "see capture" -- did you mean to post a screenshot or stack trace of your error?

Comment: You must click on the link RACT-NATIVE RUN-ANDROID to see the error on a capture

Comment: Do you have any extra info on what might be going on before line 167 in events.js?

Comment: In the project I can not find events.js file
This project is the simple react-native get-start AwesomeProject

Comment: Did you run the build command prior to running the run-android command? Did you run the link command prior to running the build command?

Comment: what is th build command : **npm start**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolution. I almost opened two console: one I compile with

> **npm start**

and the other run

> **react-native run-android**